# efficient way to compare elements in lists (in java)

Tags: list, compare

It's complex and I don't know if there is a efficient way to do the compare 
Here is the sample data:

```
    timestamp      value1  value2   
    1406481868169   ABC     10
    1406481868180   ABC     10
    1406481868188   ABC     10
    1406481868193   ABC     10
    1406481868193   EDF     12
    1406481868169   EDF     12
    1406481868180   EDF     12
    1406481868169   XYZ     30
    1406481868188   XYZ     20
```

First,  I need group these items if they have the time stamp. in this sample data, the groups will be:

```
---group1-------
1406481868169   ABC     10
1406481868169   EDF     12
1406481868169   XYZ     20
----group2-----
1406481868180   ABC     10
1406481868180   EDF     12
----group3-----
1406481868188   ABC     10
1406481868188   XYZ     30
----group4-----
1406481868193   ABC     10
1406481868193   EDF     12
```

Then I need find the match groups. that means the two group has the same number of elements and the element has the equal value1 and value2.
for example, in the sample data, group2 matches group4.
Going further, I like to have a way to find >xx% matches groups. for example, group 1 has 2 out 3 elements match group 2 or group4.
Is there any efficient way to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: It depends on what data-structures you are using but a good way to do it it's using hashTables; I have made a simple animation to help that you can found in this [link](http://whatthehell.hol.es/private/projects/stackoverflow/listsInJava/) . Press next to go step-by-step. Please let me know any doubt or comment.

Comment: Thank sergioFC for your detailed demonstration and I'm working on it now.